# Nextflow: pass reads variable to process in another script

Tags: nextflow

I'm new to nextflow, channel, process. Kindly bear with me. I'd like to create a pipeline, pass paired reads from one to another process. I am unable to do it.

script1.nf

```
params.outdir = 'results'

params.reads1 = "/Users/user/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R1_xxx.fastq.gz"

params.reads2 = "/Users/user/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R2_xxx.fastq.gz"

println "reads: $params.reads1"

println "reads: $params.reads2"

Channel.fromPath(params.reads1,checkIfExists: true).view()

Channel.fromPath(params.reads2,checkIfExists: true).view()

include { fastp } from '/Users/name/Documents/name/nextflow_scripts/fastp.nf'


fqpairs_ch=channel.fromFilePairs('/Users/name/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R{1,2}_xxx.fastq.gz')


process check {

    output: 
    stdout


    """ 
    echo "hello from command line \n"

    """

}

workflow {

    check().view(). /// this works

    fastp(fqpairs_ch).view() // it gives error

}
```

fastp.nf

```
params.outdir = "./results"

process fastp() {

tag "$sample_id"


input:
        tuple val(sample_id), file(x), file(x1) from fqpairs_ch


output:
println ("$sample_id")


    script:

    """ 

mkdir fastp_trimmed

        fastp \
        --correction \
    --cut_tail \
    --disable_trim_poly_g \
    --length_required 50 \
    --qualified_quality_phred 20 \
    --thread 12 \
    --trim_poly_x \
    --unqualified_percent_limit 20 \
        -i ${x[0]} -I ${x[1]} \
        -o fastp_trimmed/joinedfiles.dat_${x[0]} -O fastp_trimmed/joinedfiles.dat_${x[1]} 

    """

}
```

Error:

> ERROR ~ No such variable: fqpairs_ch
>
> -- Check script 'fastp.nf' at line: 13 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details

I'm unable to wrap by head around tag, val. Also, it is difficult for me to understand how to pass variable from one script to another. I've watched Youtube tutorial but with limited success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` keyword can be used to import functions, processes and other workflows into your main workflow script<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-inclusion)</sup>. Note that when using the new [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html), the `from` and `into` channel declarations can be ommitted<sup>[2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#process-definition)</sup>. Here's one way, tested using [Conda](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/conda.html).

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
params.reads = '/Users/name/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R{1,2}_xxx.fastq.gz'

include { fastp } from './modules/fastp'


workflow {

    read_pairs = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    fastp( read_pairs )

    fastp.out.reads.view()
}
```

Contents of `modules/fastp/main.nf`:

```
process fastp {

    tag { sample_id }

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads, stageAs: 'input_reads/*')

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_{1,2}.trimmed.fastq.gz"), emit: reads
    tuple val(sample_id), path("fastp.html"), emit: html
    tuple val(sample_id), path("fastp.json"), emit: json

    script:
    def (fq1, fq2) = reads

    """
    fastp \\
        --correction \\
        --cut_tail \\
        --disable_trim_poly_g \\
        --length_required 50 \\
        --qualified_quality_phred 20 \\
        --thread ${task.cpus} \\
        --trim_poly_x \\
        --unqualified_percent_limit 20 \\
        -i "${fq1}" \\
        -I "${fq2}" \\
        -o "${sample_id}_1.trimmed.fastq.gz" \\
        -O "${sample_id}_2.trimmed.fastq.gz"
    """
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
params {

    outdir = './results'
}

process {

    withName: fastp {

        publishDir = [
            [
                path: "${params.outdir}/fastp/reads",
                pattern: "*.fastq.gz",
                mode: 'copy',
            ],
            [
                path: "${params.outdir}/fastp/reports",
                pattern: "fastp.{html,json}",
                mode: 'copy',
            ],
        ]

        cpus = 12
        conda = 'fastp=0.23.4=hadf994f_1'
    }
}

conda {

    enabled = true
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf -ansi-log false
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [special_bhabha] DSL2 - revision: 6e2f1c4478
Creating env using conda: fastp=0.23.4=hadf994f_1 [cache /path/to/work/conda/env-069bf10c907949d763dee91ac82cdee5]
[cf/1cbcdb] Submitted process > fastp (baz)
[ae/3f33c5] Submitted process > fastp (bar)
[8a/37deb8] Submitted process > fastp (foo)
[bar, [/path/to/work/ae/3f33c5a956b91d0e61b7c42f059249/bar_1.trimmed.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/ae/3f33c5a956b91d0e61b7c42f059249/bar_2.trimmed.fastq.gz]]
[baz, [/path/to/work/cf/1cbcdbb27ad021bbc3e40fbb4892b1/baz_1.trimmed.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/cf/1cbcdbb27ad021bbc3e40fbb4892b1/baz_2.trimmed.fastq.gz]]
[foo, [/path/to/work/8a/37deb820eb932b790a2806c86b0cd6/foo_1.trimmed.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/8a/37deb820eb932b790a2806c86b0cd6/foo_2.trimmed.fastq.gz]]
```

I've used the [`stageAs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=stageas#input-type-path) input file/path option to ensure we never (accidentally) clobber our input files when `fastp` is run. Specifying an output filename that ends with `.gz` also ensures we always produce gzip-compressed output<sup>[3](https://github.com/OpenGene/fastp#input-and-output)</sup>. If we had instead used the original filename as a suffix, we could potentially produce uncompressed output if our input files were also uncompressed (i.e. do *not* end with `.gz`) which might be unexpected.

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to understand 1) folder structure, that is, wouldn't there be a fastp.nf? I see that you've put `modules/fastp/main.nf:` 2) At which folder level do I put the config file? 3) where is `${params.outdir}` is defined? 4) what does `fastp.out.reads.view()` do? This is an extended code.

Comment: @DeathMetal No worries - you could absolutely `include` a file called `fastp.nf` if preferred. I've just used a [module directory](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-directory) to structure the code. The `nextflow.config` should live in the root directory of your project repository (i.e. alongside the `main.nf` with the main `workflow` block). It has a `params` scope that sets the `outdir` variable. The `view()` prints the items emitted by the `fastp.out.reads` channel. This is a 'named output channel', please see: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#process-output

Comment: Hi, how do I create `$sample_id` directory using nextflow.config for fastp process? Or, `params.outdir/${sample_id}/quality` in the config file?

Comment: @DeathMetal Use a closure instead: `path: { "${params.outdir}/${sample_id}/quality" },`

Comment: as process takes all the input file is there a way I can limit number of files in the process? `.take` limits the file to a limit, for example, `.take(4)` will only process 4 files out of all files. Is there a way to process 4 files at a time instead of 20/30/whatever is the input files, eventually next 4 and so on? i am unable to follow scatter/gather.

Comment: @DeathMetal I think what you want is the [`collate`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collate) operator?

Comment: Don't know. It errors out as `WARN: Input tuple does not match input set cardinality declared by process FASTP`

Comment: can you please look into the thread in binfo stack exchange: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/nextflow-tumor-normal-sample-how-to-make-code-organic

Comment: Sorry @DeathMetal if I get time I will try and add an answer.