# nextflow: create index - get path

Tags: nextflow

my apologies for another nextflow post. I'd like to create index of a reference genome. I have two scripts: main.nf and create_index.nf

**main.nf**

```
params.hg38genome ="/Users/name/Downloads/NM.fasta"
params.outDir = "./output"

include {create_index} from './index.nf'

workflow {
create_index(params.hg38genome)    
}
```

I've following code in **index.nf**

```
process create_index {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir "${params.outDir}/hg38index/", mode:"copy"
debug true

    input:
path( params.hg38genome)

    output:
    path("${params.outDir}_refhg38.fai"), emit: hg38_fasta_index

    script:


    """
    echo "hello $params.hg38genome $params.outDir  \n"
bwa index $params.hg38genome

    """
}
```

I am unable to get any value in sample_id
Second, I get error as:

> Caused by:   Missing output file(s) `./output_refhg38.fai` expected by
> process `create_index (null)`

If I run bwa as:
`bwa index input.fasta`

I get files as where `input.fasta` is located.

```
input.fasta.ann  
input.fasta.amb     
input.fasta.sa  
input.fasta.bwt     
input.fasta.pac
```

How do I enable nextflow to create folder output and within it NM.fasta.X where X is ann, etc. Also, it doesn't extract NM.fasta I tried with `${params.hg38genome}.baseName`  but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because you've declared a file that could not be found in your process working directory. Note that the FASTA index file (i.e. the `.fai` file) is not actually an output of `bwa index`. You might be thinking of `samtools index` which does indeed create the FASTA index `.fai` file. If your next step is to align some reads, you don't even need the FASTA index file - you only need the BWA index files. For example:

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
params.reads = '/Users/name/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R{1,2}_xxx.fastq.gz'
params.hg38genome = '/Users/name/Downloads/NM.fasta'

include { bwa_index } from './bwa.nf'
include { bwa_mem } from './bwa.nf'


workflow {

    reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    hg38genome = file( params.hg38genome )

    bwa_index( hg38genome, hg38genome.name )
    bwa_mem( reads, bwa_index.out )

    bwa_mem.out.view()
}
```

Contents of `bwa.nf`:

```
process bwa_index {

    input:
    path ref_fasta
    val prefix

    output:
    tuple val(prefix), path("${prefix}.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}")

    """
    bwa index \\
        -p "${prefix}" \\
        "${ref_fasta}"
    """
}
```

```
process bwa_mem {

    tag { sample_id }

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)
    tuple val(idxbase), path("bwa_index/*")

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}.aln.bam")

    script:
    def task_cpus = task.cpus > 1 ? task.cpus - 1 : task.cpus

    """
    bwa mem \\
        -t ${task_cpus} \\
        "bwa_index/${idxbase}" \\
        ${reads} |
    samtools view \\
       -1 \\
       -o "${sample_id}.aln.bam" \\
       -
    """
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
params {

    outdir = './results'
}

process {

    withName: bwa_index {

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.outdir}/bwa_index",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
        cpus = 1
        conda = 'bwakit=0.7.17-dev1'
    }

    withName: bwa_mem {

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.outdir}/bwa_mem",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
        cpus = 8
        conda = 'bwakit=0.7.17-dev1'
    }
}

conda {

    enabled = true
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf -ansi-log false
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [determined_jang] DSL2 - revision: 1f32b172b7
Creating env using conda: bwakit=0.7.17-dev1 [cache /path/to/work/conda/env-c67b42794b99b0cecbbb27e78e7f5fb7]
[f6/10ac19] Submitted process > bwa_index
[7a/76be98] Submitted process > bwa_mem (foo)
[foo, /path/to/work/7a/76be98292ced9ca7e418470227b34a/foo.aln.bam]
[de/9d97f1] Submitted process > bwa_mem (baz)
[baz, /path/to/work/de/9d97f1270464644149ec0b64903a49/baz.aln.bam]
[4a/83079c] Submitted process > bwa_mem (bar)
[bar, /path/to/work/4a/83079c009dd7f28306c1f5108426ff/bar.aln.bam]
```

Comment: Hii @Steve thank you. In `bwa_index ` I'm unable to understand `tag { ref_fasta.name }` what does this do specifically **.name**. Second, when to use tuple, for example `tuple val(ref_fasta.name)`. Second, `tag { ref_fasta.name }` and `path(ref_fasta)` give same value. How do I know what to use what.

Comment: In `bwa_mem` how does the script know `path(idx_files)` and `val(idxbase)` ? I would guess it is from `bwa_index.out` but it's not clear. This is counter intuitive. When do I use `path(reads)`?

Comment: `"${params.outdir}/bwa_index"` doesn't work? It doesn't generate `bwa_index` folder. Neither `./results` is created. I have `config.nf` as you've. BWA index files are created in `./.work/ae/g2628930928/`

Comment: @DeathMetal I just call [`getName()`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes) to get the file name without any parents, but it's superfluous. Note that the `bwa_index` output declaration is the sample as the `bwa_mem` input declaration (i.e. the second channel). In both instances, it is a tuple where the first element is a `val` and the second element is a `path`. I will make some changes soon.

Comment: @DeathMetal A better way might be to feed a prefix into `bwa_index`. If you only use it once in your workflow, it doesn't necessarily even need a tag. Although you can add one if you wish. The `bwa_mem` process now stages the BWA index files in a subdirectory, which keeps things tidy. Please see my changes above. Not sure what is causing an issue publishing the outputs to the publishDir, sorry.

Comment: Thank you tremendously. I appreciate you for helping me. I come from programming background and thus these challenges. I still cannot follow what to use when. For example, in your code above you do not use `emit` neither in `*.nf` nor in `config.nf` . I believe that allows to capture using `.out` for e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469515/2740831

Comment: When do I use `tag`? I can develop pipeline in bash/shell scripting but nextflow has a steep learning curve.

Comment: If I run script with index without tag in `bwa_index` it complains/errors as `ERROR ~ No such variable: prefix` I used code without index (that is earlier).

Comment: @DeathMetal The [`emit`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#process-named-output) option just lets you name your output channels. It is useful for when a process defines multiple output channels. If your process outputs only a single channel, accessing it using a name is probably unnecessary. If a process will be executed multiple times (like `bwa_mem` for each sample), it is helpful to `tag` these with some custom label (so you can know what jobs/samples failed for example). If a process will only be run once in your workflow, a `tag` may not help much when it comes to debugging.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. Would you be able to assist at post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493667/nextflow-how-to-pass-directory-path-with-files-created-in-process-before