# nextflow: error while running gatk - command runs fine on command line without xmx options

Tags: dsl, nextflow

I do not provide any XmXX, etc. settings whilst running gatk. I run my main.nf on login node of a HPC server

I have **main.nf**
params.outdir_fastp="/sc/arion/projects/name/user/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/trimmed"

```
params.outdir_index="/sc/arion/projects/path/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwa_index"

params.rawFiles = "/sc/arion/projects/user/name/tiny/tumor/*_R{1,2}_xxx.fastq.gz"
params.outdir_bwa_mem="/sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem"

params.hg38genome ="/sc/arion/projects/user/name/reference_genome/neisseria_meningitidis/NM.fasta"
params.gatk_mark_duplicates="/sc/arion/projects/username/path/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/gatk_mark_duplicates"

include { FASTP} from './fastp_process.nf'
include {bwa_index} from './index_process.nf'
include { align_bwa_mem} from './bwamem_process.nf'
include { gatk_markduplicates} from './gatk_markduplicates_process.nf'

workflow {

        read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.rawFiles )
        FASTP(read_pairs_ch) 
        bwa_index(params.hg38genome)
        align_bwa_mem(FASTP.out.reads,bwa_index.out) 
        gatk_markduplicates(align_bwa_mem.out.sorted_bams)
}
```

I have **gatk_markduplicates_process.nf**

```
process gatk_markduplicates {

debug true

    publishDir params.gatk_mark_duplicates , mode:"copy"

    input:
        tuple val(sample_id), path(sorted_bam) 
        
    output:
        tuple val(sample_id),path("${sample_id}.dedup.sorted.bam")
        tuple val(sample_id),path("${sample_id}.markdup.metrics.txt")

script:

"""
        echo "$sample_id ${params.outdir_bwa_mem}/${sorted_bam}\n"      
        ml gatk/4.1.3.0

        gatk MarkDuplicates -I ${params.outdir_bwa_mem}/${sorted_bam} \\
        -O ${sample_id}.dedup.sorted.bam \\
        -M ${sample_id}.markdup.metrics.txt

"""
}
```

I get error as:

```
Error executing process > 'gatk_markduplicates (2)'

Caused by:
  Process `gatk_markduplicates (2)` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  echo "tiny_t_L007 /sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L007.sorted.bam
  " An e
  # hs_eml gatk/4.1.3.0
  
          gatk MarkDuplicates -I /sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L007.sorted.bam \
          -O tiny_t_L007.dedup.sorted.bam \
          -M tiny_t_L007.markdup.metrics.txt

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  tiny_t_L007 /sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L007.sorted.bam
  
  #
  # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
  # Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
  # An error report file with more information is saved as:
  # hs_err_pid148553.log

Command error:
  tiny_t_L007 /sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L007.sorted.bam
  
  
  The following have been reloaded with a version change:
    1) java/11.0.2 => java/1.8.0_211
  
  Using GATK jar /hpc/packages/minerva-centos7/gatk/4.1.3.0/gatk-4.1.3.0/gatk-package-4.1.3.0-local.jar
  Running:
      java -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_read_samtools=false -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_samtools=true -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_tribble=false -Dsamjdk.compression_level=2 -jar /hpc/packages/minerva-centos7/gatk/4.1.3.0/gatk-4.1.3.0/gatk-package-4.1.3.0-local.jar MarkDuplicates -I /sc/arion/projects/user/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L007.sorted.bam -O tiny_t_L007.dedup.sorted.bam -M tiny_t_L007.markdup.metrics.txt
  #
  # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
  # Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
  # An error report file with more information is saved as:
  # hs_err_pid148553.log

Work dir:
  /sc/arion/projects/user/name/nextflow_pipeline/scripts_pipeline/work/e1/0b2f8095e9b0caf074691786ed4c1e

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

The following runs fine:

```
gatk MarkDuplicates -I /sc/arion/projects/name/name/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L003.sorted.bam         -O tiny_t_L003.dedup.sorted.bam         -M tiny_t_L003.markdup.metrics.txt
```

Or following also works fine:

```
java -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_read_samtools=false -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_samtools=true -Dsamjdk.use_async_io_write_tribble=false -Dsamjdk.compression_level=2 -jar /hpc/packages/minerva-centos7/gatk/4.1.3.0/gatk-4.1.3.0/gatk-package-4.1.3.0-local.jar MarkDuplicates -I /sc/arion/projects/username/path/output_pipeline_nextflow/test_tiny_datasets/bwamem/tiny_t_L001.sorted.bam -O tiny_t_L001.dedup.sorted.bam -M tiny_t_L001.markdup.metrics.txt
```

Comment: Probably best to avoid testing your workflow on a login node. It would be much better to run `nextflow` on a compute node using an interactive session. Are you also using the `local` executor? Or have you defined an [executor](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html) in your `nextflow.config` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just out of memory here. If you haven't specified how much memory the job is allowed to use using the [`memory`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#memory) directive, it's likely your job is being submitted with whatever the default value is, as determined by your job scheduler. This is often a low number (e.g. 1 GB) and is less than what the JRE requires to run GATK. For a coordinate sorted BAM, using the [`--ASSUME_SORT_ORDER`](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037052812-MarkDuplicates-Picard-#--ASSUME_SORT_ORDER) option might also be helpful here, for example:

```
process gatk_markduplicates {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir params.gatk_mark_duplicates, mode: "copy"

    module 'gatk/4.1.3.0'
    memory 8.GB    

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(sorted_bam) 
        
    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}.dedup.sorted.bam"), emit: bam
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}.markdup.metrics.txt"), emit: metrics

    script:
    def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga() : 0
    def java_options = [
        avail_mem ? "-Xmx${avail_mem}G" : "",
        "-Djava.io.tmpdir='\${PWD}/tmp'",
        "-XX:+UseSerialGC",
    ]

    """
    gatk \\
        --java-options "${java_options.join(' ')}" \\
    MarkDuplicates \\
        --INPUT "${sorted_bam}" \\
        --METRICS_FILE "${sample_id}.markdup.metrics.txt" \\
        --OUTPUT "${sample_id}.dedup.sorted.bam" \\
        --ASSUME_SORT_ORDER coordinate
    """
}
```

Note that your [`input`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) block will ensure that the sorted BAM is staged into the process working directory. Using an absolute path here (i.e. `params.outdir_bwa_mem`) to access a different file outside of this directory with the same file name is ***not*** what you want.

Comment: If I don't provide absolute path there's error :
  `Tcl_InitNotifier: unable to start notifier thread`
  `sh: line 1: 311467 Aborted                 /usr/bin/tclsh` `/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/RC2lua.tcl /opt/hpc/packages/minervacentos7/modulefiles/java/.modulerc`
`  Lmod has detected the following error: Unable to parse:`
`  "/opt/hpc/packages/minerva-centos7/modulefiles/java/.modulerc". Aborting!`

Comment: @DeathMetal Weird. I don't see how it's related, but in any case it looks like there's a problem with your Java `.modulerc` file and is probably a question for your sysadmin. This might also explain why your Java gets downgraded, but that's just a guess. A workaround could be to replace the modules with Conda or Singularity/Apptainer containers.

Comment: thanks. I was able to run this today (after 3days). It turns out I can only run it with one sample. For e.g.,  if six samples are put through then Java would need say, need 120Gb of memory. Is there a way to limit files processed in nextflow so memory isn't gobbled up? I'd process ~300-400 human genome samples.

Comment: @DeathMetal You could use the [`maxForks`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#maxforks) directive (e.g. `maxForks 6`) for this, but I suspect this is an XY problem. [Minerva](https://labs.icahn.mssm.edu/minervalab/minerva-quick-start/) uses [LSF](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#lsf) for batch submission, so what you probably want instead is to add `process.executor = 'lsf'` to your `nextflow.config`. And set the `cpus`, `memory`, `queue` and `time` directives to set the resource request(s).

Comment: @DeathMetal I just noticed the typo in the error: `Unable to parse: "/opt/hpc/packages/minerva-centos7/modulefiles/java/.modulerc"`. The directory path has changed: `minerva-centos7` should be `minervacentos7` (or vice versa).